# Continuous Deployment of a electron app using GitLab

Tags: gitlab, electron

I am developing a desktop app on a Linux machine. The code is hosted on GitLab.com. I'd like a sample gitlab-ci.yml on building the app for Windows. I'm out of ideas on how to go about this, any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The build steps depends on the library you are using to build the electron app. Here is a sample using `electron-builder`

```
// .gitlab-ci.yml
stages:
  - build

build:
  image: electronuserland/builder:wine
  stage: build
  script:
    - yarn
    - yarn dist:win
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 30 days
    paths:
      - ./dist/
  only:
    - master

// package.json
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        ...
        "dist:win": "electron-builder -w",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I feel this question is more related to electron itself rather than GitLab CI. In the runner config you perform all tasks you'd normally perform while developing the app locally. So you should put all the stuff you usually put into your build tasks locally into the CI config.

Comment: the problem Jimmy have is for bundling electron you will need specific environments for example. you can not build `.dmg` file any other os other then OSx.. etc etc. same goes for windows app as well.